# Change style of a fixed position Div based on the current Div behind it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a single page scrolling website where all pages appear one after the other on a single URL.

I have a fixed footer, I want to change the styling of footer div according to the current div visible on the screen.

i.e. the styling of my footer should change with scrolling of the page based on the current position where the user is at or based on the current Div behind it.

Is it possible in CSS ? or using some jquery plugin? or I will have to use some custom jquery?

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle link with your code.

Comment: @NathanLee [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLJ3k/) it is for a better picture. I want to change the background color of my footer div based on the div currently behind it.

Comment: Do you mean, you need to apply a ` background-color: transparent;` to the `footer` class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making it transparent?

Or look at this code: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

There is a bar below that changes size and color depending on scrolling.

Comment: transparent wouldn't do it... because it would look strange only the text being fixed with scroll.
but this plugin would certainly do it.. yes the bar that changes size and color.. that's what I need. thanks!